# How to tell typescript that an array is not empty in a map method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using the && operator in react to map an array if that array is not empty. However, later when it is mapping I'm trying to access the current element's id, and it's giving me the following error because it thinks that the array can be empty, even if I'm running a check before the map to make sure that it is not empty:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'array'.
> Property 'id' does not exist on type '[]'.ts(23

This is my code

```
const RenderArray = () => (<div>{(Array.isArray(array) &&
        array.length) &&
        array.map((item, idx) => {
            const currentItem = anotherArray.find(
                (data) => data.id == item.id
            )
            return <div></div>
        })}
</div>
```

)

the first array has the following types:

```
type array = [] | {
id: string;
name?: string | undefined;
quantity: number; }
```

EDIT: the second array has these types:

```
const anotherArray: {
id: string;
name: string; }[]
```

Comment: What is the type of `anotherArray`?

Comment: @Hcaertnit just edited the quetion to include the other array types. Sorry about that!

Comment: `type item = { id: string; name?: string | undefined; quantity: number; };` followed by `type array = item[] | item;` you have to type the array otherwise typescript will assume you are trying to make an empty tuple with `[]`

Comment: @JacobSmit Yeah, the thing is the array can be empty, that's why I added the `[]`. Let me explain, the component is going to fetch some data. That data will have an id, a name and a key value that contains an array, which can be empty . If it's empty, then I don't want to map the array, but if it's not, then I want it to map it. Sorry for not explaining this in the post, I removed a lot of code that I thought that would be more confusing.

Comment: Thats not how the types work, an empty array is still defined as an array of type X i.e. `X[]` if the type is unknown you could use `unknown[]` or if you don't care about the type you could use `any[]` "empty array" is not a type it is a state of the array. it would be different if the value could be `undefined` or `null` and the type would be more along the lines of `type array = item[] | item | null | undefined;`.  `Array.map` won't map anything for an empty array, empty array in = empty array out, there are no items to iterate. Do your state checks as part of your code not your typing.

Comment: @JacobSmit Oh, I see! That makes sense. Sorry, I'm kinda new to typescript so I googled if there was a type for an empty array and I found that I should use `[]` lol. But yeah, I understand what you're saying, you explained it really well. Thank you so much!